# В чём причина ошибки syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING?

Tags: php

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php
    if (!isset ($_GET['login']))
    {
        <...>
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Активный пользователь:$_GET['login']"; // В чем причина ошибки, при попытке использовать $_GET['login']???
    }
    ?>
```

Она устраняется, если использовать

```
$_GET[login] //Без кавычек
```

или

```
 {$_GET['login']}
```

или конкатенацию, но мне хочется узнать причину ошибки.

Comment: У вас еще пробел после isset, которого не должно быть, это функция

Comment: @korytoff пробелы перед скобками разрешены, это не нарушение синтакисиса. `isset`, кстати, не функция, а языковая конструкция, к ней применяются немного другие правила (к слову о неконсистентости PHP).

Comment: @Etki насчет проблема да, был не прав. А вот isset это все таки функция для работы с переменными. В нее передается аргумент и она возвращает результат + еще в документации так же написанно – http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php

Comment: Автору вопроса на заметку ссылка на документацию – http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: @korytoff прямо со страницы по ссылке: *Замечание: Поскольку это языковая конструкция, а не функция, она не может вызываться при помощи переменных функций.* На деле это ззначит, что ее нельзя вызвать через `call_user_func`, например.

Comment: @Etki да, ты прав, не заметил это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеются баги в php

Bug в php [#16195](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16195) - когда работаете с переменными `GET`/`POST` они не работают как стандартные массивы. И вот получаются эти проблемы.

Bug [#15498](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=15498) - Возможно это проблема из за того, что переменные `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` и `$_SERVER["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` 
содержат значение переменных  `GET` и `POST` данных, соответственно.

Bug [#10502](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=10502) - тоже проблема с `POST` значениями

Для рещения лучше использовать *Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис*

---

**Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис**

Он называется сложным не потому, что труден в понимании, а потому что позволяет использовать сложные выражения.

Любая скалярная переменная, элемент массива или свойство объекта, отображаемое в строку, может быть представлена в строке этим синтаксисом. Просто запишите выражение так же, как и вне строки, а затем заключите его в `{` и `}`.

Поскольку `{` не может быть экранирован, этот синтаксис будет распознаваться только когда `$` следует непосредственно за `{`.

Используйте `{\$`, чтобы напечатать `{$`.

*Замечание:*
Попытка доступа к переменным других типов (исключая массивы или объекты, реализующие определенные интерфейсы) с помощью `[]` или `{}` молча вернет `NULL`.

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
<?php
// Показываем все ошибки
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$great = 'здорово';

// Не работает, выводит: Это { здорово}
echo "Это { $great}";

// Работает, выводит: Это здорово
echo "Это {$great}";
echo "Это ${great}";

// Работает
echo "Этот квадрат шириной {$square->width}00 сантиметров.";

// Работает, ключи, заключенные в кавычки, работают только с синтаксисом фигурных скобок
echo "Это работает: {$arr['key']}";

// Работает
echo "Это работает: {$arr[4][3]}";

// Это неверно по той же причине, что и $foo[bar] вне
// строки. Другими словами, это по-прежнему будет работать,
// но поскольку PHP сначала ищет константу foo, это вызовет
// ошибку уровня E_NOTICE (неопределенная константа).
echo "Это неправильно: {$arr[foo][3]}";

// Работает. При использовании многомерных массивов внутри
// строк всегда используйте фигурные скобки
echo "Это работает: {$arr['foo'][3]}";

// Работает.
echo "Это работает: " . $arr['foo'][3];

echo "Это тоже работает: {$obj->values[3]->name}";

echo "Это значение переменной по имени $name: {${$name}}";

echo "Это значение переменной по имени, которое возвращает функция getName(): {${getName()}}";

echo "Это значение переменной по имени, которое возвращает \$object->getName(): {${$object->getName()}}";

// Не работает, выводит: Это то, что возвращает getName(): {getName()}
echo "Это то, что возвращает getName(): {getName()}";
?>
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы текст ошибки разобрать?

Comment: извините какую текст ошибку?

Comment: ТС в заголовке вопроса ошибку текст ошибки написал. До статьи из источника, что у вас в ответе, я тоже дошёл. Но я не смог понять, что эта ошибка из себя представляет. Было бы здорово, если бы вы детально проанализировали эти слова, если возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Причина ошибки в том, что ты в двойных кавычках пишешь символ одинарных кавычек `'`, предполагая, что это ключ элемента массива, но *php* распознает эту одинарную кавычку как ничего не значащий символ. Это тоже самое, что написать `echo "Активный пользователь:$_GET[+login-]";` или `echo "Активный пользователь:$_GET[.login?]";` или что-то в этом роде. Таким образом ты пытаешься обратиться к ключу `'login'` (а не `login`), имя которого начинается не с буквы или символа подчеркивания, а с `'`, что является ошибкой. Как правильно делать ты уже сам разобрался и еще *@Saidolim* расписал.